# Internet Explorer printing loses text

Tags: internet-explorer, printer

When I try to print a page ... such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms136031(v=SQL.90).aspx I lose a good portion of the text on the right-hand side of the page.

It's the text in the tables that seems to be affected, the text at the top of the page wraps correctly.

I can usually make all the text appear on the page by printing in Landscape mode, but ironically, the MSDN page I cited as an example is still too wide for that.

I'm using IE6 on Windows XP - and it's a work machine so I can't change either of these.

This also happens a lot if I try to print an IE page to OneNote on my own machine (Windows 7, uwsing IE8), for instance the MSDN pages where I want to print the product key pages loses the information on the right, and keeps the left hand navigation column only. BUT, if I print these same pages on Chrome to OneNote, I get everything on one page.

As I said, it's a work machine and I can't use Chrome on there.

Is IE setup in some wierd and funky way that I need to change ?

I tried doing page setup and changing the margins to 25mm all round, but this didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I pretty much migrated to Google chrome - it allows me to synchronise my bookmarks between machines automatically, and prints to OneNote and CutePDF, and paper perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

IE is terrible at handling frames when it comes to printing them. Instead of fiddling with printing settings for all eternity, I use an external site like "[Print What You Like](http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/)"...

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a shrink to fit option that can be configured under page setup in IE. The downside is it does make the rest of the text quite small.

Don't think this is available in IE6 as we had the same issue here at work but decided to move to ie8 after the spate of ie6 exploits that started roaming around the web.  I will do some searching through my notes on it in case there was a work around we found for ie6.

EDIT:  Looking through my notes the only workaround we could find without installing a myriad of addons and bespoke hacks was to get the users to print in landscape as opposed to portrait.  Hope this helps though i fear it is not what you were looking for.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I usually try Landscape mode but on this occassion the page is still too wide.

I'm going to request a download of Chrome. Or, possibly the portable version from www.portableapps.com if they won't let me install software.